# django | File "manage.py", line 16 ) from exc ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: django

Tras crear la base de datos de nuevo y ejecutar "python manage.py makemigrations" devuelve el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué ha sucedido?

manage.py

```
**#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'aguas.settings.local')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()**
```

Answer (score 1):

No había activado el entorno virtual. Por ese motivo devuelve este error.
Disculpad.

Comment: ¡No olvides aceptar tu respuesta! Tu pregunta podría ser relanzada al inicio una y otra vez por el bot Comunidad si no aceptas algunas respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista no se ve nada mal, no editaste accidentalmente el archivo y se le movió la indentacion o algún espacio que accidentalmente se haya introducido? Te recomiendo primero cerciorarte que el código este bien formateado, ya que es común que salga ese error por la indentacion, también te podría salir si te faltara algún paréntesis pero si están balanceados.

Comment: Disculpa era simplemente que no había iniciado el entorno virtual. Disculpa.